# static method with private methods within it [C#]

Tags: c#, static-methods

I wanted to make a **class** *Draw* which will have **static method** *ConsoleSquare()* and I wanted to make all other methods in that class hidden (**private**).But I got errors in marked places and I don't know how to solve them and still achieve the same idea ( *ConsoleSquare()* - static ; all other methods hidden )

```
class Draw {
private string Spaces(int k){
    string str="";
    for(;k!=0;k--)
        str+='\b';
    return str;
    }
private string Line(int n,char c){
    string str="";
    for(;n!=0;n--)
        str+=c;
    return str;
    }
public static void ConsoleSquare(int n,char c){
    string line  = Line(n,c); // ovdje
    string space = c + Spaces(n - 2) + c; //ovdje
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    for (; n != 0; n--)
        Console.WriteLine(space);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare them as `private static`.

Answer (score 9):

A static method cannot call instance methods unless you explicitly provide an instance. Mark `Spaces` and `Line` as static as well if you want to call these directly from `ConsoleSquare`.

Comment: But then methods _Spaces()_ and _Line()_ will be visible to the end-user of class (like any other **static** method) and thats what I'm trying to avoid. Because methods _Spaces()_ and _Line()_ don't have any stand alone function ,they are just building parts used in _ConsoleSquare()_ method. Is there any solution which will respect the idea of my problem ? (_ConsoleSquare()_ method as static, _Spaces()_ & _Line()_ methods **hidden** [unlike static] )

Comment: @kr85: They are already declared `private` so they will *not* be available outside of `Draw`.

Comment: Note that a static method can call instance methods *if it has an instance to call them on*.

Comment: @Eric: Sure, but I wanted to keep my answer simple.

Answer (score 3):

you need an instance to call an instance method. You can't call an instance method from a static method without providing an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Make the private methods static too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you encapsulate all `Draw` related methods in another class. Don't put any static method in there. Let all the methods be public in that too.

Define another class; call it `DrawUI` or something. Let this have the static method. In this static method instantiate the `Draw` class, use its methods